# javadoc doesn't found in my linux machine

Tags: java, linux, jvm, javadoc

I'm running on ubuntu 12.04 and when I put in the terminal `java -version` I got this message:

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

but despite that, if I put in the terminal `javadoc` I receive a message as it isn't installed in my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) doesn't include  `javadoc`. It includes only the things required to *run* Java programs, not to develop them.

You need the JDK (Java Development Kit) which includes developer tools like `javadoc`, in addition to everything found in the JRE.

See the Ubuntu Java [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

Comment: I had already downloaded JDK and extract it on /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0. inside jdk1.7.0 folder I have bin,lib,ecc...where is the mistake?

Comment: `java` and `javadoc` are separate commands, so just because one works, does not mean the other works. As you can see from the following link, each command may need setting up separately, if you have not used a package install: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Comment: Check that you have both commands in the `bin` directory. Then run `which java ` and `which javadoc` to see whether Ubuntu can find them.

Comment: to Mazzy: I suffered from this problem too then I realized that i had both jdk and jre rpms installed.  I removed them and re-installed just the jdk rpm and now all is good!